# Need to format output from function in powershell

Tags: powershell, formatting, output

I have script written in powershell which get the Fibonacci series between 0 to N.

Code:

```
$n = $args[0]
Function Get-Fib ($n) {
     $current = $previous = 1;
     while ($current -lt $n) {
           $current;
           $current,$previous = ($current + $previous),$current}
     }
Get-Fib $n
```

**Input: & .\script2.ps1 7**

**Expected Output: 1 1 2 3 5**

But, now output look like this:

**1**

**2**

**3**

**5**

*is it possible get output without a newline in this script?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build up the output like this

```
Function Get-Fib ($n) {
    $output = ""
    $current = $previous = 1;
    while ($current -lt $n) {
        $output += "$current "
        $current,$previous = ($current + $previous),$current
    }
    $output
}

Get-Fib 100

1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89
```

Or you can enclose the entire code section in a subexpression `$(...)` and then join together with a space like this.

```
Function Get-Fib ($n) {
    $current = $previous = 1;
    $(
    while ($current -lt $n) {
        $current
        $current,$previous = ($current + $previous),$current
    }
    ) -join " "
}

Get-Fib 100

1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89
```

Comment: In first option I think we should change a little bit here, $output +=  "  " + $current .
The second option is just brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying the function just modify the caller side:

```
( Get-Fib 6 ) -join ' '
```

By enclosing the function call in parenthesis, we get the result as an array which can be joined using the `-join` operator.

This way the function keeps its flexibility. Following the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle), the function should not be concerned about formatting, it should just do its base job, that is calculating and output the result in the native data format.

This allows us to use the function in a greater variety of contexts, e. g. pass its output to other cmdlets that expect a sequence:

```
( Get-Fib 6 | Sort-Object -Descending ) -join ' '
```